# FreeBSD: lldb does crash even in hello.c

Tags: freebsd, lldb

on FreeBSD I started to play around with LLDB, but it crashes right at the start.

```
user@host ~/sandbox % rake hello
cc -I/usr/local/include -g -O0 -o hello.o -c hello.c
cc -Wl,-L/usr/local/lib -o hello hello.o
user@host ~/sandbox % lldb
(lldb) target create hello
Current executable set to 'hello' (i386).
(lldb) source list
 8    {
 9        printf( "Hello, world!\n");
 10       return 0;
 11   }
 12
(lldb) breakpoint set -f hello.c -l 9
Breakpoint 1: where = hello`main + 31 at hello.c:9, address = 0x080485af
(lldb) process launch
Process 2409 launching
Process 2409 stopped
(lldb) Process 2409 launched: '/usr/home/user/sandbox/hello' (i386)
Process 2409 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 100224, 0x0818188f, stop reason = hardware error
    frame #0: 0x0818188f
-> 0x818188f:  addb   %al, (%eax)
   0x8181891:  addb   %al, (%eax)
   0x8181893:  addb   %al, (%eax)
   0x8181895:  addb   %al, (%eax)
(lldb)
```

It is the same on three machines.

I have also tried Gdb on Linux. There, everything worked fine.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Bertram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLDB doesn't support FreeBSD/i386 host for now. Use recent gdb from ports or switch to amd64.